# How would I write a CouchDB view that would list the size of each stored document?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'd like to know the size of the documents that are stored within my CouchDB database.  How would I write a view that would list the size of the documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found this to be acceptable (incorporating Marcello's comment):

```
function(doc) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(doc);
  emit(json.length, null);
}
```

Edit: incorporating @dch's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12356648/515065), this is a more complete estimate of over-the-wire size but as he notes, this is not the size of the document on disk.

```
function(doc) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(doc);
  var len = json.length;
  if (doc._attachments) {
    for (var attachmentKey in doc._attachments) {
      var attachment = doc._attachments[attachmentKey];
      len += attachment.length;
    }
  }
  emit(len, null);
}
```

Comment: Two notes. Use `var json = ...` to avoid declaring or, worse, modifying a global variable. As noted by @dch, you should add the size of every attachment.

Comment: great! One last tip: you should avoid putting the `doc`s in the index. It will double your storage requirements. Use [`include_docs`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) instead.

Answer (score 3):

As usual the answer depends a little on what you are intending to do with that data.

- in CouchDB 1.2.0 and on, snappy compression will ensure that the on-disk size of each document is quite a bit smaller than your stringify calculation.
- in any case, CouchDB store JSON as encoded erlang terms, which is not a 1-for-1 size equivalence either.
- attachments will not be recorded in your approach but are available in the stub metadata:

`{
  "_id":"555b17372035fdeb9b4077c68e00053f",
  "_rev":"3-a6fa3aadf3bf64f11b721d7d4333e9ec",
  "_attachments":{
    "preview.png":{
      "content_type":"image/png",
      "revpos":3,
      "digest":"md5-fNhm5TL2NFnsujYKixr+3A==",
      "length":328076,
      "stub":true
    }
  }
}`

Comment: You're right, the stringify won't give me on disk size but it will give me over the wire size which is what I'm interested in.  You're also right that I neglected attachments.  I don't use them in my application but I'll update the answer so that it is more complete.  Thanks!